# Getting a value from a list

Tags: javascript

I have a list like that:

```
<select size="1">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

How can I get the value of this options with JavaScript (Getting the "1", "2", "3" and so on...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add the `id` of "list" to `<select>` this should work: **[Example Here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/V3ZnB/)**

```
document.getElementById('list').onchange = function( e) {
    alert( this.value )
}
```

to get it directly without using `this`:

```
document.getElementById('list').value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;
```

or

```
mySelection = function(element){
    console.log(element.value);
}

<select onchange="mySelection(this);">
```